# Return Value in Column B Table 2, where column A Table 1, matches Column A Table 2

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm trying to do: Where ***category*** *(projects)* matches ***id*** *(markets)* echo ***category*** *(markets)*.

**Table 1 Sample (*projects* table)**

[image: projects table]

**Table 2 Sample (*markets* table)**

[image]

**Sample of PHP Code**

```
$num_rec_per_page=5;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 

 function GET($key) {
    return isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] : null;
}

$category= GET('category');

if ($category !== null) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE category='$category' LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page";
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page";
}

$sql_query = mysql_query($sql);
$post = $sql_query;

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM markets";
$sql_query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
$marketsinfo = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query1);
```

In my code below, I've tried putting a while loop within the main while loop since we have to find out what category its in then display it for each blog post.

It only worked for the first result, and then I did some research online and found that it is very poor design to do this.

Where I'm currently at with displaying the result (see code in between hyphens):

```
            <!-- Blog - Start -->
        <?php while ($post = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query)) {?>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 blog blog_altered blog_left">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Blog Image - Start -->
                <div class=" col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-10 col-xs-12  pic inviewport animated delay1" data-effect="fadeIn">
                    <img alt="blog-image" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $post['imageoutside'] ?>">
                </div>
                <!-- Blog Image - End -->
                <!-- Blog Info - Start -->
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 inviewport animated delay1" data-effect="fadeIn">
                    <div class="info">
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                        <span class="date">
                        <?php
                            if($post['category'] === $marketsinfo['id']){
                                echo $marketsinfo['category'];
                            }
                         ?>
                         </span>
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                        <h4 class="title"><a href="projects/readmore.php?job=<?php echo $post['job'] ?>"><?php echo $post['title'] ?></a></h4>
                        <p><?php echo $post['summary'] ?></p>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary text-on-primary"  href="projects/readmore.php?job=<?php echo $post['job'] ?>">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Blog Info - End -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
            <!-- Blog - End -->
```

Hope I've been thorough enough without being confusing. How can a noob accomplish this? I'll take any pointers you have!!

Comment: Learn to use `Joins`.  https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ provides a brief overview.

Comment: Also, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a join, you can get the category text in one query and avoid all the looping in PHP.

A LEFT Join will return all records from Projects and only those records which match from markets.  So if a projects category doesn't exist in markets, a NULL value will be returned.

If you used a INNER JOIN, only records which have corresponding values in BOTH tables would be returned.

Rule of thumb: get the data you need from the database in 1 trip when you need it. Format in PHP, Datagrab in SQL.  Don't get more than you need, and don't get less.

```
SELECT P.Job, M.ID as Markets_ID, M.Category, P.Title
FROM projects P
LEFT JOIN Markets M
 on P.Category =M.ID 
WHERE P.category='$category'   
LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page"
```

Note: you will need to put a table alias on category in the where clause.  I'm assuming your passing in the ID so P.Category was used.

Comment: and an ORDER BY clause

Comment: Also, I would caveat that by saying that for smaller datasets, it's fine to just grab the whole thing as a bit of json, say, and handle the pagination in PHP/javascript.

Comment: Thank you for this! I didn't know such a helpful MySQL feature existed. Is there any documentation on how I could use this inside of my while loop though? My while loop lists the jobs as they are ordered in the database. Would I need to create a variable inside of the while loop based on some unique identifier and put the SQL_query outside of it, while using the variable in the WHERE clause? [While Loop Output](http://prnt.sc/dwryag)

Answer (score 0):

do you want join table projects with tables market by category?
may be u can do this

```
SELECT p.id as id
     , m.category as category 
  from projects as p 
  left 
  join markets as m 
    on p.category = m.id 
 WHERE m.category='$category' 
 LIMIT $start_from
     , $num_rec_per_page
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN m... WHERE m` is the same as `INNER JOIN m ...`

Comment: yes its the same but if using left join when u dont't have related column,this will become null CMIIW